# Is pagination can be allowed in Discussion Board?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is pagination allowed in replies page of the Discussion Board list? i.e is it possible to show only 5 replies in a page of a discussion? If possible how? If not suggest an appropiate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes pagination is poosible in discussion board list

1. go to list settings
2. edit the flat View
3. set Item limit to 5 by default
   it would be at 25